# Why can I not edit in vue3 quill editor?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, quill

I am doing a test with the vue3 quill editor, this is what it currently looks like:
[image]

The quill editor gets displayed, but I cannot edit the text.

This is my code:

### HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <quill-editor
    v-model:value="state.content"
    :options="state.editorOption"
    :disabled="state.disabled"
    @blur="onEditorBlur($event)"
    @focus="onEditorFocus($event)"
    @ready="onEditorReady($event)"
    @change="onEditorChange($event)"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { quillEditor } from 'vue3-quill'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      content: '<p>2333</p>',
      _content: '',
      editorOption: {
        placeholder: 'core',
        modules: {
          // toolbars: [
            // custom toolbars options
            // will override the default configuration
          // ],
          // other moudle options here
          // otherMoudle: {}
        },
        // more options
      },
      disabled: false
    })

    const onEditorBlur = (quill) => {
      console.log('editor blur!', quill)
    }
    const onEditorFocus = (quill) => {
      console.log('editor focus!', quill)
    }
    const onEditorReady = (quill) => {
      console.log('editor ready!', quill)
    }
    const onEditorChange = ({ quill, html, text }) => {
      console.log('editor change!', quill, html, text)
      state._content = html
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      state.disabled = true
    }, 2000)

    return { state, onEditorBlur, onEditorFocus, onEditorReady, onEditorChange }
  },
  components: {
    quillEditor
  }
}
</script>
```

### Commands

These are the commands that I did to create the project.

```
vue create .
```

```
with default vue 3 options
```

```
npm i vue3-quill
```

I found the command and code here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-quill

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   state.disabled = true
}, 2000)
```

disable the editor.
Just remove them or exchange true for false